# Adding single python bokeh label

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bokeh

I am trying to add a single label at a specific spot on a bokeh chart. I know this easy but I can't seem to find the code that works for me.

I am trying to use the Label in bokeh.models but it isn't working.

[image]

I know the exact x and y coordinates, text and text color but it isn't working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show 
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
from bokeh.models import Label

output_notebook()

graph = figure(title = "Average Yearly Temperature per US State",) 

for state in us_state_temps.columns:
    if state == 'California':
        graph.line(us_state_temps.index, us_state_temps[state], line_width         = 2, color = "red")
    else:
        graph.line(us_state_temps.index, us_state_temps[state], line_width = 0.5, color = 'gray')
    
graph.xaxis.axis_label = 'Year'
graph.yaxis.axis_label = "Average Yearly Temperature °C"
graph.toolbar_location = None
graph.toolbar.active_drag = None

california = Label(x=70, y=1960, x_units='screen', y_units='screen',         text='California')

graph.add_layout(california)
hover = HoverTool()
hover.tooltips = [('Year', '@x'), ('Average temp.', '@y')]
graph.add_tools(hover)


show(graph)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. As a block of code, not a picture, so it could be easily copied and executed.

Comment: What version of bokeh are you using?